# How should an app clarify that you can choose the outcome size only during the first 2 of the 4-step process?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, web-app, mobile-application, artificial-intelligence

I am working on an app that synthesizes long texts, articles, essays.
You paste in the text and the system starts synthesizing.

You can choose a size or length for the final format, say Short, Medium, Elaborate only during the first two steps of the four-step process.
How do I make it clear that the user can only do that during the first two steps?

Yes, we could ask the question before the user clicks "Start" but we wanted to make it as quick as possible: upload and hit "Start"; then you can choose.

Comment: Can user go backward?

Comment: Hi there, yes but will have the option to change format as long as the process hasn't passed the 2nd step

Answer (score 0):

Make the only one step where user will be able to choose size or length. This is usual behavior for step-by-step process rather than making possible to make the same actions in different steps. Furthermore user have ability to return back to the step with settings if he will be not satisfied with following steps results.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a confirmation dialogue between steps 2 and 3 to tell that user know that once step 2 is passed, you can make changes to the final format. This is the clearest it can get.

However, if the back button works, i don’t see the need to do anything, you just need to display clear messages to the user to be sure that any changes to the final format can only be made on the first 2 steps.

[image: confirmation dialogue example]